# Send a timstamp in JSON via Postman

Tags: json, postman

I'm fairly new to working with REST APIs and Postman and I'm looking for a way to include a timestamp as a string in a POST request body via Postman.

According to the [Postman docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/environments), there is a dynamic variable `{{$timestamp}}` which can be used in the request body. However, when I try to use it, I get a 400 back from the endpoint I am POSTing to with the message "malformed data."

Here are a couple of variations I have tried:

### variation 1

```
[
    {
        "from_number": "+123456789",
        "messages": [
            {
                "text":  "Message at" {{$timestamp}},
                "to_number": "+123456789"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

### variation 2

```
[
    {
        "from_number": "+123456789",
        "messages": [
            {
                "text":  "Message at {{$timestamp}}",
                "to_number": "+123456789"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

### variation 3

```
[
    {
        "from_number": "+123456789",
        "messages": [
            {
                "text":  "Message at " + {{$timestamp}},
                "to_number": "+123456789"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

All of these have returned the same error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "malformed data",
  "error": true
}
```

Comment: The second variation is the correct one, even if the dynamic `$timestamp` variable doesn't work. Are you sure about the expected body format ?

Comment: I can verify that variation 2 is correct. Something else is wrong.

Comment: @NimS You're right. I just tried variation 2 again successfully. I must have missed a character before or something. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks @NimS and @JAAulde: Varation 2 is the correct answer. The problem must have been a typo.